# Area optimization algorithm for Palletts in truck

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I want to calculate how to optimally fit a number of palletts (red) into a truck (black) so that the used lenght of the loading space is as short as possible.

Is it possible to solve this problem with the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)?

[image]

Comment: No, as the knapsack approach won't take geometric shapes and unused gaps into account.

Comment: This is a 2d-packing problem. This can be formulated as a Mixed-Integer Programming problem. OR-Tools CP-SAT solver has a built-in `AddNoOverlap2D(x,y)` constraint which makes it easier to formulate these (and it is usually much faster than a MIP model).